# Angularjs: call a controller method with param from a directive dropdown on change event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have made a dropdown directive. On selecting a value from the dropdown, a method from the controller is called with the selected filter passed. Everything works fine except that the method is always returning the default selected value, no matter, what is selected.

html:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div>
          <dropdown filters="filters" filter="filter" select="selectFilter(filter)"></dropdown>
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

function Ctrl($scope){

    $scope.filters = [
       { Id: 1, Name: "All" }, { Id: 2, Name: "filter1" }, { Id: 3, Name: "filter2" }, { Id: 4, Name: "filter3"}
    ];

    $scope.filter = $scope.filters[0];

    $scope.selectFilter = function(selectedFilter){
      alert(selectedFilter.Name);  
    };
}

app.directive('dropdown', function(){
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            filter: "=",
            filters: "=",
            select: "&"
        },
        template: "<select ng-model=\"filter\" ng-change=\"select(filter)\" ng-options=\"f.Name for f in filters\"></select>"

    };
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wXV6Z/98/

Comment: It isn't, it's returning the previous value rather than the new one, as that what you are sending to the function

Comment: You are right about sending the previous value, but how do I make it send the new value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using wrong syntax to call method binding.

Try:

```
ng-change=\"select({filter:filter})\
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VFmDQ/)

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Can You explain '{filter:filter}' part, please ?

Comment: @Mdb: the first `filter` is the parameter name in your expression `selectFilter(filter)`, the second `filter` is the parameter's value

Comment: @KhanhTO can you maybe elaborate, I have to admit I don't understand how that works.

Comment: @Mosho: With the expression `selectFilter(filter)`, we specify that this function has 1 named parameter (`filter`). To call it in your directive, you have to specify both the parameter's name and its value.

Comment: @KhanhTO but why does it get the previous value as parameter if you just do what the OP did, as opposed to what you did? (I know we're not supposed to chat here but I don't get it and I assume other people won't either)

Comment: @Mosho: This is by accident. To answer why, I think we need to dig into angular's source code.

Comment: Then maybe my answer is the way to go after all :P

Answer (score 1):

I made this, but the other answer seems better :P

http://jsfiddle.net/wXV6Z/101/

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

function Ctrl($scope, $element){

    $scope.filters = [
       { Id: 1, Name: "All" }, { Id: 2, Name: "filter1" }, { Id: 3, Name: "filter2" }, { Id: 4, Name: "filter3"}
    ];

    $scope.filter = $scope.filters[0];

}

app.directive('dropdown', function(){
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            filter: "=",
            filters: "=",
        },
        template: "<select ng-model=\"filter\" ng-change=\"selectFilter(filter)\" ng-options=\"f.Name for f in filters\"></select>",
        controller: function($scope, $element) {
            $scope.selectFilter = function(selectedFilter) {
                alert(selectedFilter.Name);  
            }
        }   
    }
});
```